# Expand and collapse multilevel sections in uitableview swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to expand and collpase the multilevel array in uitableview like the following

- Cat1

  - SubCat1

    - Info 1
    - Info 2
  - SubCat2

    - Info 1
    - Info 2
  - SubCat3

    - Info 1
    - Info 2
- Cat2

  - SubCat1

    - Info 1
    - Info 2

For that purpose I have done the following code.

```
struct CellData {
var opened = Bool()
var subCatTitle = String()
var subCatList = [String]()
}
struct MainModel {
var opened = Bool()
var categoryTitle = String()
var categoryList = [CellData]()
}
```

I have made the list

```
 @IBOutlet var expandableThreeStageTableView: UITableView!
    var arrayList = [CellData]()
    var expandableList = [MainModel]()

func loadData(){
    arrayList.append(CellData(opened: false, subCatTitle: "SubCat1", subCatList: ["Info1","Info2","Info3"]))
    arrayList.append(CellData(opened: false, subCatTitle: "SubCat2", subCatList: ["Info1","Info2","Info3"]))
    arrayList.append(CellData(opened: false, subCatTitle: "SubCat3", subCatList: ["Info1","Info2"]))
    arrayList.append(CellData(opened: false, subCatTitle: "SubCat4", subCatList: ["Info1"]))

    expandableList.append(MainModel(opened: true, categoryTitle: "Cat1", categoryList: arrayList))
    expandableList.append(MainModel(opened: false, categoryTitle: "Cat2", categoryList: arrayList))
    expandableList.append(MainModel(opened: false, categoryTitle: "Cat3", categoryList: arrayList))
}
```

And delegate, datasource methods are given below

```
extension TextFieldAsSearchVC : UITableViewDataSource{
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return expandableList.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
        if expandableList[section].opened{
            if expandableList[section].categoryList[section].opened{
                return 
expandableList[section].categoryList[section].subCatList.count////which extra count should return here
            }else{
                print("COUNT ",expandableList[section].categoryList.count)
                return expandableList[section].categoryList.count + 
1///here +1 is for catname + subcatname

            }
        }else{
            return 1
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            let cell = 
expandableThreeStageTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"TextFieldAsSearchVCCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldAsSearchVCCell
            cell.lblValue.text = 
expandableList[indexPath.section].categoryTitle
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row <= 
expandableList[indexPath.section].categoryList.count{
             let cell = 
expandableThreeStageTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"SectionDataCell", for: indexPath) as! SectionDataCell
            cell.rowLabel.text = 
expandableList[indexPath.section].categoryList[indexPath.row - 
1].subCatTitle
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = 
expandableThreeStageTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"SectionDataCell", for: indexPath) as! SectionDataCell
  cell.rowLabel.text = 

 expandableList[indexPath.section].categoryList[indexPath.row].
subCatList[indexPath.row]//how to access rows in subcategories
            return cell
        }
    }
}
extension TextFieldAsSearchVC : UITableViewDelegate{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            if expandableList[indexPath.section].opened{
                expandableList[indexPath.section].opened = false
                //now reload the section
                let sections = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
                expandableThreeStageTableView.reloadSections(sections, 
with: .automatic)
            }else{
                expandableList[indexPath.section].opened = true
                //now reload sections
                let sections = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
                expandableThreeStageTableView.reloadSections(sections, 
with: .automatic)
            }

        }else {
            if 
expandableList[indexPath.section].categoryList[indexPath.row].opened{

expandableList[indexPath.section].categoryList[indexPath.row].opened = 
false
                expandableThreeStageTableView.reloadRows(at: 
[IndexPath(index: indexPath.row)], with: .automatic)
            }else{

expandableList[indexPath.section].categoryList[indexPath.row].opened = 
true
                expandableThreeStageTableView.reloadRows(at: 
[IndexPath(index: indexPath.row)], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From above code I can expand and collapse the Categories but not Subcategories.. When I tried to click on Subcategories it gives me an error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use 
with UITableView. Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly 
two indices specifying the section and row. Please use the category on 
NSIndexPath in NSIndexPath+UIKitAdditions.h if possible.'
```

How to deal with such type of logic?

Comment: Instead of using cell for each data Use stackview inside a cell and hide/show SubCats

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are getting occurs in this line:

`expandableThreeStageTableView.reloadRows(at: 
[IndexPath(index: indexPath.row)], with: .automatic)`

An `IndexPath` needs both, a `row` and a `section`; you're only providing a row. So it should be something like this:

`expandableThreeStageTableView.reloadRows(at: 
[IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)], with: .automatic)`

If you really only need to reload the current `indexPath`, simply call it like this:

`expandableThreeStageTableView.reloadRows(at: 
[indexPath], with: .automatic)`

This would fix the error you are getting, but I don't know if that solves your problem or not.

Comment: thanx, second solution has reloved an error. but now how to access index(rows) in SubCat[] in 'cellForRowAt' method

Comment: I believe you have multiple errors in your code. First of all, inside your `numbersOfSectionInTableView` implementation: you're wrongly calculating the number of subCategories. You are doing this: 

`if expandableList[section].opened{  if expandableList[section].categoryList[section].opened {`

So you will never reach an entry like `expandableList[0].categoryList[1]`. You will have to rethink your logic here. An `IndexPath` only provides one section and one row. What you want is an `IndexPath` which has a `section`, a `subsection` and a `row`.